# Undefined index AJAX Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, controller

I'm using laravel with json pass my data to controller. Everything seems work fine in html template file. But when comes to controller, $_GET method didn't work at all. Undefined index.

**Route**

```
Route::post('/live/{stream_active}/{vid_url}', 'Controller@getAjax');
```

**Controller**

```
public function getAjax($stream_active,$vid_url)
{
    $stream_active = "1";
    $vid_url = $_GET['vid_url']; //Undefine index

    $input = Input::all();
    $full_path = "http://xx.xxx.xx.xx/vod/".$vid_url;

    $input['stream_active'] = $stream_active;
    $input['vid_url'] = $full_path;
    $this->video->create($input);
}
```

**AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
        url : '/live/{stream_active}/{vid_url}',    
        type : 'POST',
        data : { stream_active : '1', vid_url : path_url},
        success : function (data)
        {
            alert('Updated completed.');
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First it doesn't work because you're actually sending a POST request. But also because you have the parameter in your route you would actually use it in the URL when making the call:

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/live/1/'+path_url,    
    type : 'POST',
    success : function (data)
    {
        alert('Updated completed.');
    }
});
```

And then use the variables that get injected into your controller:

```
public function getAjax($stream_active,$vid_url)
{
    $full_path = "http://xx.xxx.xx.xx/vod/".$vid_url;

    $input['stream_active'] = $stream_active;
    $input['vid_url'] = $full_path;
    $this->video->create($input);
}
```

---

The alternative solution would be to remove the parameters from the URL and send the data like you currently do:

```
Route::post('/live', 'Controller@getAjax');

$.ajax({
    url : '/live',    
    type : 'POST',
    data : { stream_active : '1', vid_url : path_url},
    success : function (data)
    {
        alert('Updated completed.');
    }
});


public function getAjax()
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $input['vid_url'] = "http://xx.xxx.xx.xx/vod/" . $input['vid_url'];
    $this->video->create($input);
}
```

Comment: For the alternative solution, it doesn't concatenate with my full path, instead of $vid_url individually. @lukasgeiter

Comment: Oh I missed to assign the full path. Take a look at the updated answer.